# Is there a forum-like exchange for trading Bitcoins person-to-person?

Tags: exchanges, trading, paypal, otc

I was to trade Bitcoins for PayPal quite frequently and I know that PayPal doesn't allow Bitcoin exchanges to accept PayPal payments.
But there should exist a person-to-person trading site that works like a forum and where people choose how to pay each other, no?

I know about bitcoin-otc, but I'd prefer a forum-like concept better instead of IRC.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Trading Bitcoins using PayPal exposes you to risk of chargebacks and possible PP account suspension if they find out what you are doing. Not the wisest thing to do.

Comment: I know the risks of using PayPal, but I am looking for such a service, it can have multiple sections.
There are those like bitcoin.de and bitmarket.eu but they limit the payment types themselves instead of allowing user-defined ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for has just been released.

Bitcoinary. https://www.bitcoinary.com

[image: Bitcoinary Screenshot]

Comment: Ah it's you, Ian himself. Yeah I checked it out and already made my first purchase through it. Sadly I have to tell you that I think you launched way too early. A lot of things are half-ready and the site is loading really slow. I hope you have additional functionality ready to launch, because I really like the concept.

Comment: Hi Steven. I had to launch as early as possible to make sure it's something people want and to gather feedback. I've got a list of about 20 enhancements to add over the next week or so. I'd appreciate you letting me know what things are half ready just in case I've missed something. You can do this through the contact page or on the bitcointalk thread. Thanks.

Comment: Site performance has improved greatly and lot's of bugs have been fixed. More functionality coming this week.

Comment: We may get a little off-topic here, but is this a project you do on your own? I've been thinking of launching such a web service as well (because I was desperately looking for a decent one), but as a student, didn't have time to work it out since I had a lot of work for school the last few months.

Answer (score 5):

LocalBitcoins.com has person-to-person PayPal trading:

http://localbitcoins.com/buy-bitcoins-online/paypal

https://localbitcoins.com/sell-bitcoins-online/paypal/

There are also discussion forums where people frequently discuss about PayPal, avoiding fraud there, etc. Here is an example:

https://localbitcoins.com/forums/#!/trading#getting-paypal-scammedive

LocalBitcoins.com has also trusted buyers list where you can set your trading parties trusted and make trading offers available only for them (to avoid scammers).

Comment: localbitcoins require you to put in a minimum amount before you can post a sell advertisement

Comment: LocalBitcoins.com uses escrow system where you need to have the bitcoins in your wallet when you post your own online sell advertisement. However, this is not true for cash trades or online buy advertisements.

Answer (score 4):

You can trade Bitcoins for PayPal on #bitcoin-otc on FreeNode IRC, just make sure you deal with people with a good reputation, and that you use the rating system correctly.

http://bitcoin-otc.com/

Comment: I said I know bitcoin-otc, but the whole setup for that is a little too advanced for daily use :)

Answer (score 1):

If you dont like bitcoin-otc ( but imho its the best solution ) , you can try https://ogrr.com

There are also some trading on the marketplace section of bitcointalk : 
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=5.0

But beware, the scammers are many on the forums, only the web of trust system on bitcoin-otc will help you avoid scammers.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of places to cash out bitcoins and get the payout through PayPal.

- http://www.SpendBitcoins.com
- Tangible Cryptography: http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=85395.0
- http://www.BitcoinNordic.com
- http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Selling_bitcoins

Comment: How does tangible cryptography work?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try Silk Road, there you can buy/sell Bitcoin, among other things.

Not sure about the rates, though.

Comment: This one could do with an update. Silk Road 2.0 is up and running for the time being but who knows how long for?

Answer (score 0):

I use [bitcoin2pocket.com](http://bitcoin2pocket.com/) quite a lot, fast bank transfers if you are located in the UK. I think they also have set up Paypal payments for people who live outside the UK.

Answer (score 0):

[CoinTouch](https://www.cointouch.com/) (my site) puts  you in touch with find friends of friends that want to trade bitcoins.

CoinTouch shows offers to buy and sell within your extended social network. Prices are pegged to market rates (MtGox or CoinDesk), at your chosen spread, and thus automatically update every minute.

There are no fees, no delays and no BS.

CoinTouch can price in all major world currencies. More altcoins coming soon. Currently supports Facebook login - Google and LinkedIn coming soon.

Any feedback, please drop me a tweet [@cointouch](http://www.twitter.com/cointouch)

Thanks, and I hope you find the site useful

Answer (score 0):

[Bitalo.com](https://bitalo.com/) is a person-to-person exchange much like [LocalBitcoins](https://localbitcoins.com/) and [bitcoin.de](https://www.bitcoin.de/). SEPA transfers are recommended for making the fiat payment. Bitcoins are kept in multi-signature wallets, and time-lock escrow is used during the trade.

The multi-signature solution is similar to the [GreenAddress.it](https://greenaddress.it/g) and [BitGo](http://bitgo.com/) wallets – the service doesn't hold the user's private key and isn't capable of taking the user's funds.