# Has anyone here used bitcoins to swap dollars for pesos in Argentina?

Tags: exchanges, exchange-rate, travel, argentina

I've seen some chatter online about using bitcoins as a workaround for Argentinian currency controls (see below) and I'd like to speak to people who have actually done that, whether it means converting pesos to bitcoins to dollars or vice-versa. Was it cumbersome? Did you save money?

[Can I use bitcoin as a means of bypassing Argentine Dollar restrictions?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5735/can-i-use-bitcoin-as-a-means-of-bypassing-argentine-dollar-restrictions)

Comment: I had not tried pesos/bitcoins exchange in Argentina (yet), but from my experience living in other countries with similar currency exchange restrictions, you'll unlikely save money this way. Generally speaking, most bitcoin sellers (most of thise are reselers) are buying btc abroad from international exchanges, so their expenses will be included to the rate. But if someone has another experience, it will be very interesting to hear success stories)